# can I strcmp() a char[] with char*

Tags: c

Right now I have a `char[] A` that I want to strcmp() with `char* B`.

Can I just do `strcmp(A, B)` or do I have to convert `A` into a `char*`?

And if I do have to convert, do I just do this?:

```
char* convertedA = A
```

Comment: Do both `A` and `B` have a null (`'\0'`) terminator?

Answer (score 1):

Unless it is the object of the address-of operator `&` or the `sizeof` operator, an array is converted to a pointer to its first element anyplace it is used.

So you can safely pass a `char []` to a function expecting a `char *`, assuming the array contains a null-terminated string.

Comment: can you do a strncpy between char* and char[]?

Comment: @whattheels Yes, of course. `char *` and `char []` are *entirely equivalent* unless used with `sizeof` or `&`.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. Assuming both are null terminated.

Comment: @whattheels — when you pass either a `char *` or a `char []` to a function, what's passed is actually a `char *`, so any function that takes a `char *` can take a `char []` instead.  There are caveats like "a string literal should not be modified" and "usually, the arrays must be null terminated (but `strn*()` functions relax that rule) but you can generally use either.

Comment: @whattheels As long as you have enough room in the destination for the copy to fit.